# Import Excel file into rally

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs, rally

How can, I import excel file into rally and update features of existing features.

The Excel consists of multi selection options.

Please share the approach as I am new to work on rally using **ExtJS** ?

I have created a App which uploads excel file further approach would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the excel add-in for bulk creating data, or import excel files directly from the portfolio items page with this menu:

[image]

Comment: My Requirement is to create a button(filefield),on click i need to fetch excel data and update to portfolio items features columns.

Comment: You might be able to do something like this to read the file contents: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Then you'd have to parse the csv content though and then manually update the items via wsapi.  This feels like a lot of work to me, it may or may not even be possible...

Comment: yeah,it's lot of work,i can read contents,can u guide me,how to update items through wsapi any link where i can refer.

Comment: i'd start here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/data_models and read all the guides in that section on working with wsapi- stores, bulk operations, etc.